# Having problems changing umask in csh

Tags: shell, rhel, tcsh, csh

So i'm running RHEL 6.5 and I have a user that wants to use csh for what they are doing.  They also want the umask to be set to 002.  So I started to put 
umask 002 into .cshrc and call it a day.  However that didn't seem to work.  We logged out and logged back into the user account and it wouldn't set the umask.

Other server however are working.  I'm not sure if there is a bug.  I also did some digging and found that I still had to put 'umask 002' into the .bashrc or .bash_profile to make this work.  Not sure if that is 100% true.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

I have also tried putting the 'umask 002' string into .cshrc .login .profile after copying the default over from /etc/ and appending that to the bottom of the file.

However if I do a source .cshrc, BOOM it works just fine.

Comment: Is `.cshrc` even being read (put a debug `echo` into it)? Or is `.tcshrc` instead being read?

Comment: What's the user's login shell (i.e., what's the output of `getent passwd $username`)?

Answer (score -1):

Does the file ~/.tcshrc exist?   If so remove it.  When that file exists it ignores ~/.cshrc
If you have a Red Hat Portal login you can see the [reference](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/33900) there.